# Install Brother MFC-465CN as a network scanner

Tags: networking, scanner, brother

After far too much messing around I finally got my Brother MFC-465cn to print.  Now I'm trying to get it to scan set as a network scanner.  One issue I keep running across when trying to follow Brother's installation instructions (http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/before.html?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc465cn_all&redirect=on) is I cannot run the aa-complain because it says it cannot be found.  I can't find what I need anywhere.

I used to administer a Linux web server farm back in the early 2000s so it's not like I'm grandma trying to figure out what to do with the cupholder that pops out of the front of the computer.  This is my first time playing with Linux in several years, but still -- this is ridiculous!  It's becoming painfully obvious why Linux isn't adopted mainstream.

Is there somewhere a simple tutorial on how network scanners work?  I'm having a hard time even finding the appropriate information.  This is 2014 and people on Windows use network scanners all the time.  Surely there are is a way to do this on Linux without so much fuss and guesswork.

Thanks (and sorry for the rant, I'm getting old and cranky)
Ray

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to downloads for your printer @ http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc465cn_all&os=128.
2. Download "Scanner Driver" for 32bit or 64bit as per your OS. Install via Software Center ignoring the warning about the driver being poor quality.
3. Download "Scan-key-tool" for 32bit or 64bit as per your OS. Install via Software Center ingnoring the warning about the briver being poor quality.
4. Check the IP address of your printer.
5. Open terminal and run:

> sudo brsaneconfig2 -a name=SCANNER model=[Your Printer Model] ip=[Your Printer IP Address]

Comment: With 64 bit OS, you may have to add:    sudo cp /usr/lib64/* /usr/lib/